# How to copy image of unknown type to xclip?

Tags: linux, images, clipboard

I'm trying to use `sxiv` to pick an image and pipe that image to the clipboard.

I'm currently using this command:

```
cat "$(sxiv -foqrt ~/Pictures 2>/dev/null | sed 1q)" | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png
```

However, this would only work if the chosen file is a `png`. It doesn't work with just `-t image` on `xclip`. I have multiple file types I want to copy.

How can I get pass the file type problem?

Comment: In my tests there is no problem with passing arbitrary (e.g. random) data *to* `xclip`. There is also no problem with retrieving the same data via `xclip -o`. If the problem occurs when you try to retrieve data and use it with *another* program then please [edit] the question and name the program. For now the question suggests the problem is with `xclip`, I doubt it. Is there any error message form `xclip` or the other program? What message?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough rep to make a comment - you can get the [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) of the image using `file`, store it in a temp variable, and then pass that to `xclip`, like so:

```
filename="$(sxiv -foqrt ~/Pictures 2>/dev/null | sed 1q)"
filetype="$(file --brief --mime-type "${filename}")"
cat "${filename}" | xclip -selection clipboard -t "${filetype}"
```

Of course, if you want just image files, then you can wrap the last command in a simple `if` statement to check whether `filetype` contains the substring `image`.